# DevExpress RepositoryItemComboBox disable text input

Tags: c#, grid, devexpress

Sry for such a stupid question, but how i can disable text input in GridColumn with RepositoryItemComboBox as ColumnEdit ?

```
RepositoryItemComboBox repositoryItemComboBox = new RepositoryItemComboBox();
repositoryItemComboBox.Items.AddRange(SomeCollection.ToArray());

detailView.Columns["SomeColumnName"].ColumnEdit = repositoryItemComboBox;
```

It is necessary that column values could be selected from the SomeCollection, but could not be entered from the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i found the solution.

repositoryItemComboBox.TextEditStyle = TextEditStyles.DisableTextEditor;